# Exception has been thrown in C# Script in SSIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I was warking in SSIS 2010 to make transfaring for my project from my pc to the server 
but i faced a problem with C# Script task it working in my pc very well but in the server it's give me an erro.

This error when i execute the script

[image]

and that's the C# Script:

```
#region Help:  Introduction to the script task
#endregion
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System;// Basic Import Statement
using System.Collections.Generic; // Allows Us To Use Lists
using System.IO; // For File handles
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion
namespace ST_c47c0258ca4d4851b04d0fdb997749b9
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        #endregion
        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        #endregion
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        #endregion
        public void Main()
        {
            string inFolderName = @"\\SERVER\DWH File\SocialMedia\Source\Facebook\";
            string outFolderName = @"\\SERVER\DWH File\SocialMedia\Final Source\Facebook\";
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            string line;
            DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(inFolderName);//Assuming Test is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = folder.GetFiles("*.csv"); //Getting Text files

            using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(outFolderName + "Facebook Insights.csv"))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    lines.Add(line);

                }

            }
            foreach (FileInfo f in Files)
            {

                using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(f.FullName))
                {
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.Length == 0 || line.Contains("#") || line.ToLower().Contains("date") || line.ToLower().Contains("screen"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lines.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                    //System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(outFolderName + "TwtMentions.csv", lines.ToArray());
                }

                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(outFolderName + "Facebook Insights.csv", lines.ToArray());
                File.Delete(f.FullName);
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
    }
}
```

my question where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it's probably your folder URIs. When a package runs under your user ID, it uses your permissions, but when run from sql agent, you have to make sure it runs under the correct permissions so it will be allowed to access that network location.

See this:

http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2007/12/ssis-and-sql-server-agent.html

Comment: *The script error is highly likely a permissions problem!!* If the package works locally but not on the server, it is a very good bet that the user that is executing the package from SQL agent doesn't have permissions to the network locations in the script. The file access throws an exception, which gives you the useless SSIS script task exception. You should isolate your error message by commenting out everything after the first file access to see if that is what appears to be causing the problem.